# Powershell : How to get Antivirus product details

Tags: powershell

We have over 1500 servers. Windows 2003, 2008 and 2012. I have to gather the details of antivirus(Product Name & Version) on these servers.
There could be multiple antivirus product.
I am not sure powershell script will work on 2003 server.

So, far i tried below scripts but not got useful information.

```
$av = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Product" -namespace "root\cimv2" `
              -computername "." -filter "Name like '%antivirus%'"
```

Below script is working fine on client operating system.

```
$wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct"
$AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters # -ErrorVariable myError -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'             
            Write-host $AntivirusProduct.displayName
```

Can anybody advise me on this?
I am trying to get the details of antivirus(Product & Version) 
What do i need to do for win server 2003?

Comment: You said it's running fine on client OS. What happens on the server? An error or returns nothing?

Comment: I think AntiVirusProduct namespace is not available for server. i read somewhere.

Comment: You need to know what you want, and know how to get it before PowerShell can help you. On the client platform, it seems that you have MS Antivirus, so that wmi class is available, but you need to have a list of all antivirus products that might be available and need to know how to identify them. You might for example, check Uninstall registry key to document all software that's on the computer, then compare that list against the list of antivirus software you have. Win2003 can 'run' PowerShell if you download and install it but version is going to be old (v2), so be careful with syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already checked win32_platform class and checked uninstall class. If i use win32_platform class then some of the antivirus are not showing(F-secure). If i use uninstall registry class then i am getting too many result for same antivirus. Regarding Win2003, normally you can't install anything on server. There are some process and it require approval. If you are managing servers then you know that already.

Comment: Well, you dont have to run your script on windows server 2003. If you have wmi access to the windows 2003 server, you are all set. Uninstall reg key can be messy, yes, but You can use PowerShell's unique cmdlet or write a function to ignore duplicates. First get the data, then sift through and validate?

Comment: _If i use uninstall registry class then i am getting too many result for same antivirus_ but you will definitely know it's installed. I'd recommend relying on the uninstall key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on running processes, you could query the registry :

```
$computerList = "localhost", "localhost"
$filter = "antivirus"

$results = @()
foreach($computerName in $computerList) {

    $hive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $computerName)
    $regPathList = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
                   "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

    foreach($regPath in $regPathList) {
        if($key = $hive.OpenSubKey($regPath)) {
            if($subkeyNames = $key.GetSubKeyNames()) {
                foreach($subkeyName in $subkeyNames) {
                    $productKey = $key.OpenSubKey($subkeyName)
                    $productName = $productKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
                    $productVersion = $productKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
                    $productComments = $productKey.GetValue("Comments")
                    if(($productName -match $filter) -or ($productComments -match $filter)) {
                        $resultObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            Host = $computerName
                            Product = $productName
                            Version = $productVersion
                            Comments = $productComments
                        }
                        $results += $resultObj
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $key.Close()
    }
}

$results | ft -au
```

Example output :

```
Host      Product              Version   Comments
----      -------              -------   --------
localhost Avast Free Antivirus 10.4.2233         
localhost Avast Free Antivirus 10.4.2233
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it try.

Comment: Amended my example to make it usable with a computer list, and added `$key.Close()`

Answer (score 12):

You were on the right path, the following Powershell script works.

```
    function Get-AntiVirusProduct {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('name')]
    $computername=$env:computername


    )

    #$AntivirusProducts = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters # -ErrorVariable myError -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' # did not work            
     $AntiVirusProducts = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct  -ComputerName $computername

    $ret = @()
    foreach($AntiVirusProduct in $AntiVirusProducts){
        #Switch to determine the status of antivirus definitions and real-time protection.
        #The values in this switch-statement are retrieved from the following website: http://community.kaseya.com/resources/m/knowexch/1020.aspx
        switch ($AntiVirusProduct.productState) {
        "262144" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "262160" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "266240" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "266256" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "393216" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "393232" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "393488" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "397312" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "397328" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "397584" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
        default {$defstatus = "Unknown" ;$rtstatus = "Unknown"}
            }

        #Create hash-table for each computer
        $ht = @{}
        $ht.Computername = $computername
        $ht.Name = $AntiVirusProduct.displayName
        $ht.'Product GUID' = $AntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid
        $ht.'Product Executable' = $AntiVirusProduct.pathToSignedProductExe
        $ht.'Reporting Exe' = $AntiVirusProduct.pathToSignedReportingExe
        $ht.'Definition Status' = $defstatus
        $ht.'Real-time Protection Status' = $rtstatus


        #Create a new object for each computer
        $ret += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ht 
    }
    Return $ret
} 
Get-AntiVirusProduct
```

Output:

```
Product GUID                : {B0D0C4F4-7F0B-0434-B825-1213C45DAE01}
Name                        : CylancePROTECT
Real-time Protection Status : Enabled
Computername                : HOSTNAME
Product Executable          : C:\Program Files\Cylance\Desktop\CylanceSvc.exe
Reporting Exe               : C:\Program Files\Cylance\Desktop\CylanceSvc.exe
Definition Status           : Up to date

Product GUID                : {D68DDC3A-831F-4fae-9E44-DA132C1ACF46}
Name                        : Windows Defender
Real-time Protection Status : Unknown
Computername                : HOSTNAME
Product Executable          : windowsdefender://
Reporting Exe               : %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MsMpeng.exe
Definition Status           : Unknown
```

Comment: This will not work for the OP's question. He said that he needs to query server operating systems and the "root\SecurityCenter2" namespace is only available in client operating systems. A very annoying decision by Microsoft.

Comment: @Markus, How to add excluded files, extension in this script

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?  It's written in PowerShell v2, so if you have that installed on your 2003 servers, it will run on all the servers.  This code will give you a CSV of this data from whichever machines run the script that have a service with the description including the word "virus" (which I thought better than "antivirus" because some services use "anti-virus" instead).  If they all have access to a shared resource, you can prepend that shared resource directory to the `$Filename` variable and it will name each report starting with that computer's name and dump your reports there.

```
invoke-command -computername Server01, Server02 -filepath c:\Scripts\get_av_info.ps1
```

Assuming the script is saved as `c:\Scripts\get_av_info.ps1`, that should run it on whatever machines you specify, or if you have a CSV of all the machines you want to run the script, `ForEach` it.  I didn't try this, so I can't verify the remote invoking.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$localhost = $env:computername
$Filename = "C:\" + $localhost + "_" + $Date + "_AV_FileInfo.csv"
$AV = get-process | ?{$_.Description -like "*virus*"}
$Process = ForEach($a in $AV){
$ID = $($a.Id)
get-process -Id $ID -FileVersionInfo
}
$Process | select "CompanyName","FileBuildPart","FileDescription","FileName","FileVersion","ProductName","ProductPrivatePart","ProductVersion","SpecialBuild" | Export-Csv $Filename -NoTypeInformation
```

There are a LOT of options, I just picked ones I thought you'd want.  You could probably also combine the reports to one by adding a shared resource to the `Filename` and having it `-Append`, but you would run the risk of multiple servers trying to write to the file at the same time and failing to report at all.

You'll need to refine your results, of course.  If you don't change anything, any machine where you run this will just drop a CSV called "COMPUTERNAME_DATE_AV_FileInfo.csv" at the root of it's C:\ drive.

Comment: I can say nice thought. I will try it and let you know. only one draw back if antivirus is not running then i don't think it will return anything.

Comment: If antivirus isn't running, somebody in your department might consider finding a new career.  =P