# Force refresh AntiVirusProduct (WMI)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, antivirus

Is there a way to refresh data which can be retrieved from `AntiVirusProduct`? I am able to retrieve data using:

```
 string wmipathstr = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2";
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct");
```

The problem is that I get info about some antivirus which has been removed some time ago already (McAfee VirusScan). I checked both the location mentioned by the above query (`C:\Program Files\McAfee.com\Agent\mcupdate.exe`) and the system registry and both don't have any information about the antivirus. Is there any way to force refresh the data returned by WMI?

Comment: It's been a while but as far as I recall this information is written by the 3rd party software as needed; e.g. there's no concept of querying the software to ask it to update or refresh. These entries being left behind is just cruft that the uninstaller missed or forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How to get Antivirus product details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649043/powershell-how-to-get-antivirus-product-details)

Just give a try with this powershell function :

---

```
cls
 function Get-AntiVirusProduct {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('name')]
    $computername=$env:computername
    )

#$AntivirusProducts = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters # -ErrorVariable myError -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' # did not work            
$AntiVirusProducts = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct  -ComputerName $computername

    $ret = @()
    foreach($AntiVirusProduct in $AntiVirusProducts){
        #Switch to determine the status of antivirus definitions and real-time protection.
        #The values in this switch-statement are retrieved from the following website: http://community.kaseya.com/resources/m/knowexch/1020.aspx
        switch ($AntiVirusProduct.productState) {
        "262144" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "262160" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "266240" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "266256" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "393216" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "393232" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "393488" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"}
            "397312" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "397328" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
            "397584" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
        default {$defstatus = "Unknown" ;$rtstatus = "Unknown"}
            }

        #Create hash-table for each computer
        $ht = @{}
        $ht.Computername = $computername
        $ht.Name = $AntiVirusProduct.displayName
        $ht.'Product GUID' = $AntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid
        $ht.'Product Executable' = $AntiVirusProduct.pathToSignedProductExe
        $ht.'Reporting Exe' = $AntiVirusProduct.pathToSignedReportingExe
        $ht.'Definition Status' = $defstatus
        $ht.'Real-time Protection Status' = $rtstatus
        #Create a new object for each computer
        $ret += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ht 
    }
    Return $ret
} 
Get-AntiVirusProduct
```

Comment: This is performing the same WMI query that's in the question.  How does this solve the problem of it returning stale data?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Yes you have right this does not solve the problem and either i tested directly with command line `wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get * /Value`  the same problem that i got too :(